# FCGI & url issues while moving from Hiawatha

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, lighttpd, fastcgi, hiawatha

We are moving from Hiawatha webserver to Lighty.
I want to make this transfer as transparent as possible without making any change to FCGI application.

In Hiawatha, we have a configuration line in the UrlToolKit block

> Match ^/load_app UseFastCGI app_loader

which means, if the request URL is /load_app/index.html or /load_app/appOne or /load_app/appTwo/index.html or anything that starts with /load_app will be passed to app_loader FCGI application.
Similar to this we have many request URLs handled by different FCGI applications.
How do I get this done on Lighty?

The configuration

> "/load_app/" => (("host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 2020, "check-local"
>   => "disable" )),

only handled /load_app/index.html, but not /load_app/appTwo/index.html or /load_app/js/validate.js

I want to make this change of webserver as transparent as possible, so any lighty configuration must not change the SCRIPT_NAME, REQUEST_URI or QUERY_STRING.
Changing those variables will break the FCGI application.

Answer (score 0):

Little late now, but would this work?

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "/load_app/.*" {
    fastcgi.server = (
                       "/" =>
                         (
                           (
                             "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                             "port" => 2345,
                             "check-local" => "disable"
                           )
                         )
                     )
}
```

Should match anything starting with /load_app/.